# How to use checkbox for DOM display toggle (with objects)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing in jquery/javascript and I'm stumped. I have an input form that creates objects in an empty array, each object is a band, containing the band name and some other info.

Once these objects are made, they're displayed on the site as a list like an address book, creating a master list. Each display of the band object has a serialized checkbox, with their id's being set to 0, 1, 2, and so forth as they get created with each form submit. You can submit one band at a time, and it will add them to the array in the order you create them.

First I have an empty array to hold all the bands:

```
var bands = []; // This is the overall list of bands that have been entered.
```

Then I use this following function to add to the DOM, listing the bands out with a serialized checkbox for the users to check.

```
  var showBands = function() { // this function will add the bands to the DOM
    $("#all-bands").empty();
    var totalNumberOfBandsInAddressBook = 0;

    bands.forEach(function(band) {
      totalNumberOfBandsInAddressBook++;
      $("#all-bands").append(
        '<div class="band-list">' + "<div class='row'>" + "<div class='col.md-2'>" 
        + "<input type='checkbox' class='BandContactCheckbox' id='" + 
        (totalNumberOfBandsInAddressBook-1) + "'></input></div>" + 
        '<div class="col-md-10"><b>' + band.BandName + '</b><br>' +
        band.BandMainContactFirstName + ' ' +
        band.BandMainContactLastName + ', ' +
        band.BandEmail + ', ' +
        band.BandPhone +
        '</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>'
      );

    });
  }
```

And finally I'm stuck here, trying to get get this thing to find each checked box, no matter the order, and list the bands upon check or uncheck on the website:

```
  $('form#all-bands-form').click(function(event) { // this function will display the bands in the "Bands to Add" section dynamically with the checkboxes turned on or off
    $("input:checkbox[class=BandContactCheckbox]:checked").each(function(band) {

      var bandID = $("input:checkbox[class=BandContactCheckbox]:checked").getAttribute('id').val();
      debugger;
      $('span#bandListForShow').text('<li>' + bands[bandID].bandName + ' test1' + '</li>')
    });
  });
```

I'm pretty new to a lot of this, so full explanations are most helpful. Basically my intention with this last function here is to have a click event listener on the checkboxes which would toggle the display on or off depending on whether the box is checked. With the checkbox ID being serialized, I was hoping to use that ID number to sort through the array locations per checkbox ID, but I can't figure out how to get this 'each' method to grab the attribute value.

Comment: In your current incarnation, you are replacing the text in `$('span#bandListForShow')` each time you loop over a band with a checked checkbox. Perhaps you are attempting to build a collection of `<li>...</li>` tags to append to `$('span#bandListForShow')`?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but `'col.md-2'` should be `'col-md-2'`

Comment: `getAttribute('id').val()` is wrong. `getAttribute()` returns a string, `.val()` is used to get the value of an input. Get rid of `.val()`.

Comment: `<li>` should be appended to `<ul>`, not `<span>`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you! I'll fix that now.

Comment: @Forty3 yes, I'd like it to show each band in an ordered list on the DOM. I was assuming it'd generate the whole list each time a checkbox was checked. I know it's not optimal, but just trying to get it to display ANYTHING at this point, it's not even displaying a single band.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `.each()` loop, you should use the `band` variable (or `this`) to refer to the current element of the loop. If you use the selector again, you're referring to all the checked boxes.

You shouldn't use `.val()` after calling `getAttribute()`. `getAttribute()` returns the attribute's value already. Also, `getAttribute()` is a DOM method, not a jQuery method (the analogous `jQuery` method is `.attr()`). But you don't need any method, just `band.id` will get the ID.

To get all the bands that were checked you should be using `.append()` rather than `.text()`. `.text()` replaces the text of the element rather than appending to it; also, it doesn't parse HTML, it will show the `<li>` literally.

Before the loop that appends, you need to empty the element; otherwise you'll add to whatever was shown on the previous click.

```js
$('form#all-bands-form').click(function(event) { // this function will display the bands in the "Bands to Add" section dynamically with the checkboxes turned on or off
  $('span#bandListForShow').empty();
  $(".BandContactCheckbox:checked").each(function(band) {
    var bandID = band.id;
    $('span#bandListForShow').append('<li>' + bands[bandID].bandName + ' test1' + '</li>')
  });
});
```

Comment: AH, so the band ID isn't actually a part of the band object, I'm using the attribute ID on the checkbox itself to drive the array location for which values to append... or so that's my attempt here. 

I think I see what you're saying, I'm going to start to home in on a new solution here shortly. Thank you for your advice!